# API key Google API url get request doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, api, google-api, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to access data from Google API but it's returning a 403 okay error. Also, when I put the API key in between braces, i get a 404 error. My API key is a browser type and I pass the value in after "key=". I am sure my url is correct as I tested it in the tutorial and it returns a 202, which makes me think that something is wrong with the API key. Here's the code I'm using in my AngularJS HTTP get request:

```
var election= "https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/elections?key=" + API_KEY;


    $http.get(election)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: could you include some example code?

Comment: @comoss added the code I'm using. i defined the API_KEY earlier in my code

Comment: to test your API key just take it and dump it in a browser  example: https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/elections?key=AIzaSyD1mbbGTnmfK-rNLamwuxHk4CFTH_1WE20  Note: this will only work with a browser api key if you haven't set up any limitations on it.

Comment: nvm resolved, had to enable API in developer console. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a syntax error, add some single quote parenthesis around the url like this:

```
var election= 'https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/elections?key="' + API_KEY;
```

Comment: sorry @comoss i just forgot it, the error is still there

Comment: you could pass the string into the http.get, like this: `$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/elections?key="' + API_KEY);` that typically works for me. if that doesn't work could you make a plunker?

Comment: I accidentally did give the wrong url in my answer, which I have updated.

Comment: what's the difference between that and passing in a variable with the same value?